# Typescript cannot infer correct type from generic interface property

Tags: typescript, generics

I have some scenarios where I have an object that wields strings, numbers and booleans, and a getter that returns a value with correct type, e.g. something like this:

```
interface AllowedMapTypings {
    'str': string;
    'lon': number;
    'str2': string;
}

const obj: AllowedMapTypings = {
    'str': 'foo',
    'lon': 123,
    'str2': 'foo'
};

function foo<T extends keyof AllowedMapTypings>(key: T): AllowedMapTypings[T] {
    return obj[key];
}

let str = foo('str'); // correctly inferred type 'string'
```

However, if I use the inferred interface type as an argument, it doesn't work:

```
function fn<T extends keyof AllowedMapTypings>(key: string, kind: T, value: AllowedMapTypings[T]) {
    if (kind === 'str') {
        console.log(value.length); // Property 'length' does not exist on type 'AllowedMapTypings[T]'.
    }
}
```

It looks like the condition `kind === 'str'` doesn't do it's job as a type guard correctly.
Am I missing something, or is this a missing feature/bug in TS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known limitation, see [microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) and [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085).  The kind of control-flow narrowing that happens when you do `if (kind === 'str') {}` does not act on generic type parameters or values of such types.  I think one could argue that `if (kind === 'str') {}` should narrow the type of `kind` from `T` to `T & 'str'`, but even if the compiler did that for you it would not narrow the type of `value`.  Even though you know the type of `kind` is correlated with that of `value`, the compiler doesn't.

You can always get around this with liberal uses of [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).  If you want a bit more type safety you can use a workaround that widens the values of generic types to concrete unions, and packs correlated values into a single variable which can be narrowed the way you expect.  For example:

```
type KindValuePair<K extends keyof AllowedMapTypings = keyof AllowedMapTypings> =
  K extends any ? [K, AllowedMapTypings[K]] : never;
```

The type `KindValuePair` expands to `["str", string] | ["lon", number] | ["str2", string]`, which is the union of things you actually want to allow as `kind` and `value`.  (I could have just manually set `KindValuePair` to that union, but instead I'm using a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) to have the compiler figure it out for me.)

Then you can do this:

```
function fn<T extends keyof AllowedMapTypings>(key: string, kind: T, value: AllowedMapTypings[T]) {
  const kindValuePair = [kind, value] as KindValuePair; // assertion here
  if (kindValuePair[0] === 'str') {
    console.log(kindValuePair[1].length); // okay
  }
}
```

You assert that `[kind, value]` is of type `KindValuePair`, and then you can use control flow narrowing on `kindValuePair` to maintain the relationship you expect to see between its elements after you check against `'str'`.  If this works for you, you can even make the function concrete and not generic using [rest parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions):

```
function fn(key: string, ...kindValuePair: KindValuePair) {
  if (kindValuePair[0] === 'str') {
    console.log(kindValuePair[1].length); // okay
  }
}
```

This completely avoids assertions and is as type-safe as I can imagine making.  It also has the side effect of outlawing calls like this:

```
fn("", Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'str' : 'lon', 1); // error
```

which are allowed in the generic version (it specifies `T` as `'str' | 'lon'`).